# Getting started with building a WMS server based on Mapnik

Tags: windows, openstreetmap, wms, mapnik

I'd like to setup my own WMS server based on Mapnik to request OSM layers, but I don't find the documentation regarding that issue so clear... for example, I reached a couple of web pages stating some steps to follow concerning Mapnik and WMS:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mod_mapnik_wms

http://code.google.com/p/mapnik-utils/wiki/WmsInstallGuide

Taking into account that I'm running on Windows... which path should I follow? Or could somebody explain me how can I achieve my goal in clearer steps? And what about requesting OpenStreetMap layers through Mapnik?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try the instructions from http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mod_mapnik_wms ? Note that you can run Apache on windows.